# Is n_estimators in BaggingRegressor() the number of trees or data subsets?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bagging

I'm learning about using the `BaggingRegressor()` from scikit learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor.html)

Its `n_estimators` parameter is defined as:

```
n_estimators: int, default=10
The number of base estimators in the ensemble.
```

Am I right in thinking this changes the number of tree-based models running in total?

For example, I am using xgboost, If I set

```
BaggingRegressor(n_estimators=100)
```

is it changing the `n_estimators` in xgb to be:

- `xgboost.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100)` or does it do
- `xgboost.XGBRegressor()*100`?

Also what within `BaggingRegressor()`  decides the number of random subsets to be created if it's not the number of base estimators?

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of base estimators (not necessarily tree-based). So, if you give XGBoost as the base estimator, which I think is a bit complex to be a base estimator, it'll use 100 XGBoost models. XGBoost itself has `n_estimators` hyper-parameter but `BaggingRegressor` does not change it. It treats your estimator object as black-box.